# Не удается добавить перелистывание страниц в aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Пытался сделать перелистывание страниц для бота в aiogram, пробовал много различных вариантов.

```
    @dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'zero')
async def zero(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await callback_query.message.edit_text('тык', reply_markup=kbkb, parse_mode='HTML')

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'back')
async def back(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await callback_query.message.edit_text('back', reply_markup=kbkb, parse_mode='HTML')

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'next')
async def next(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await callback_query.message.edit_text('next', reply_markup=kbkb, parse_mode='HTML')
```

Это один из способов, при повторном нажатии на кнопку выдает ошибку:

```
aiogram.utils.exceptions.MessageNotModified: Message is not modified: specified new message content and reply markup are exactly the same as a current content and reply markup of the message
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот такое перелистывание хочу добавить. Мне трудно понимать теорию не подкрепленную примерами, поэтому если можете помочь, оставляйте пожалуйста ресурсы с подобными решениями или код. Спасибо.

Comment: Ну как вариант в стейт записать массив из страниц/данных и также впихнуть в тот же стейт переменную текущей страницы. Ну и просто применять edit_text к объекту месседж.

Answer (score 0):

для изменения `reaply_markup` есть спецыальние методы типа `bot.edit_messahe_reply_markup()` или `callback_query.message.edit_reply_markup()`